# How to create pull down menu

Tags: xamarin.forms

After click on image I want to open 2 option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options to go around this such:

1- displayactionsheet

2- Opening a model with Selection and sending the selection back

3- use [Rg.plugins.popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/) to create a popup anywhere you want on the page,..

4- [SlideOverKit](https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/SlideOverKit)

Those are alternative solutions. The closest thing to what you want is the popup plugin and SlideOverKit

Comment: I added one option that I forgot about which is actually the most closest to what you need. I also added some links. Please check them out and reply if you need anything